# Tracking in Universal Analytics - Contact form 7

Tags: contact-form-7, universal-analytics, goal-tracking

I have contact form 7 on a site. With classic analytics I had this in additional settings..

```
    on_sent_ok: "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/goals/enquiry-sent']);"
```

And it tracked fine as a destination goal. As soon as I updated to Universal analytics (including the demographics tracking), I then updated the code to:

```
    on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label');"
```

and also tried

```
    on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'pageview', '/your/url');"
```

and I just can't get either of them to track.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'sent');"
```

This works for me. Replace "Contact Form" with something you want.